Laravel: How to change default login error message: 'these credentials do not match our records' i need to change this message
Laravel - 11: How to change default login error message: 'these credentials do not match our records'
i try to search i cannot found it i need to change this message to another message laravel 11 like username or password is incorrect

How did you configure authentication?

The first thing You do is go to LoginRequest

app\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest.php

you will find this function

    public function authenticate(): void
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

    if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}


and now change trans('auth.failed') to your customized message


    public function authenticate(): void
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

    if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => 'Username or password is incorrect',
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}


you have to over write sendFailedLoginResponse method (this method is in AuthenticatesUsers traits)
in your loginController with custom message:
// other login methods

    public function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }
// other login methods

edit this part
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],

with custom message
